# Не приходит сообщение на почту?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Сайт на WP, форма WPForms, там по умолчанию {admin_email} загрузил сайт на хост timeweb, попробовал отправить заявку но на почту мне не приходит заявка, пробовал в ручную указать почту, но все равно. Что не так? Какие причины могут?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проверьте работает ли на хостинге функция [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Comment: mail та работает, т.к я создал почту хостинга и сообщения приходят, а вот на гугл почту не приходят

Comment: В спам летит. Поставьте и настройте плагин WP Mail SMTP.